# Cannot add Icon on Bootstrap Button and adding space between two Bootstrap rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

1. I'm trying to develop a thumbnail using Bootstrap 3, which on hover shows two buttons. Like this:
   [image]

In my design, the icons do not show up. Whats the problem?

[image]

I am alright with using glyphicons too. I want one button to have the link icon and the other button to have a more button.

HTML part:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
           <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="images/Layer26.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              <div class="caption">
                 <!-- Start Caption -->
                 <div class="btn-group btn-trigger">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default web-link">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default more-info">More</a>                                        
                 </div>
              </div>
              <!-- End Caption -->                  
           </div>
           <h5 class="text-center">Artist Name, city</h5>
        </div>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .Latestsignup .caption .btn-trigger{
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
    left:30%;
}

.Latestsignup .caption .btn-trigger a{
    width:44px;
    height:44px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background: transparent;
    border:1px solid white;
}

.Latestsignup .caption .btn-trigger .web-link {
    background:url(images/external_link.png) no-repeat;
}
```

HTML/CSS and Bootstrap files are [here](https://drive.google.com/?tab=oo&authuser=0#folders/0B0byAC8kZZPhd0J1ekNSNnBUamc) and the website is hosted [here](https://33ed600debf998b723a30a8a8013d39c1939389e.googledrive.com/host/0B0byAC8kZZPhd0J1ekNSNnBUamc/).

2. I want my design to look like this:

[image]

This is how it currently looks:

[image]

Obviously I will have to over-ride some bootstrap css properties. 
What do I do to reduce the distance in between images? What CSS property do I target?

I need distance in between the two rows. Even when I downsize, I want there to be distance in consecutive rows. 
The heading ( Artist Name #, City) is almost at the middle of the two images. I want it to lean towards the upper image ( as in the original design) at all time. How should this be done by CSS?

[image]

The HTML/CSS [files](https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B0byAC8kZZPhd0J1ekNSNnBUamc) are [here](https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B0byAC8kZZPhd0J1ekNSNnBUamc) and the website is hosted [here](https://33ed600debf998b723a30a8a8013d39c1939389e.googledrive.com/host/0B0byAC8kZZPhd0J1ekNSNnBUamc/).

IMPLEMENTING THE CHANGES PROPOSED BY ANONYMOUSXXX:

Here's the fiddle: http://jsbin.com/zekazumogixi/2/

Even on hover, the link and more buttons are not shown:

[image]

I've followed this fiddle: http://jsbin.com/monokivutodu/1/edit

Where have I mistaked?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested on jsfiddle, it's fine http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/pLuzpLfo/

note: because your icon to large and you want to use it for background on link, try to use size of background to decrease of icon size

```
.Latestsignup .caption .btn-trigger .web-link {
    background:url(images/external_link.png) no-repeat right 7px center;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
```

I don't know why on googledrive not calling `web-link` style (look at inspect element).

Just ask, why you not use fontawesome to get icon on link? example : http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/3tkz3g9a/

For button of "join now" you can use this element

```
 <div class="container join-now">
     <div class="row">
          <p class="text-center">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Join Now</button>
          </p>
 </div></div>
```

css :

```
.container.join-now {
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

If you want to use your style for icon, try this

```
.thumbnail{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    min-width:200px;
    width:auto;
    border:none;
}

.text-center span.text-caption{
    width:200px;
}

.caption{
    opacity:0;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(221,171,149,0.6);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5 ease-in-out;    
}

.thumbnail:hover .caption{
    opacity:1;
}

.Latestsignup {
    position:relative;
    padding:40px;

}

.Latestsignup .caption .btn-trigger{
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-44px;
    margin-top:-25px;
}

.Latestsignup .caption .btn-trigger a{
    width:44px;
    height:44px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background: transparent;
    border:1px solid white;
}

.Latestsignup .caption .btn-trigger .web-link {
    background:url(https://33ed600debf998b723a30a8a8013d39c1939389e.googledrive.com/host/0B0byAC8kZZPhd0J1ekNSNnBUamc/images/external_link.png) no-repeat right 7px center;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
.container.join-now {
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

[jsfiddle with your icon](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/pLuzpLfo/4/)

If you want to use fontawesome, try this

```
.thumbnail{
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    min-width:200px;
    width:auto;
    border:none;
}

.text-center span.text-caption{
    width:200px;
}

.caption{
    opacity:0;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(221,171,149,0.6);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5 ease-in-out;    
}

.thumbnail:hover .caption{
    opacity:1;
}

.Latestsignup {
    position:relative;
    padding:40px;

}

.Latestsignup .caption .btn-trigger{
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-44px;
    margin-top:-25px;
}

.Latestsignup .caption .btn-trigger a{
    width:44px;
    background: transparent;
    border:1px solid white;
}

.container.join-now {
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

[jsfiddle with fontawesome](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/3tkz3g9a/3/)

Comment: Hey, Not using thumbnail made a lot of sense! The design is extremely fluid now. Except for the hover icons, everything has been fixed!

Comment: Hey, If you have new code and new problem from that, you should create new question instead update old question, although the same case but the code and different problems. I know you get codes from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25322325/1297435), actually that answer is correct, you should accept that answer.

Comment: Perfect! I missed which fiddle I was following. I have accepted that answer :)